# Using database values in itextsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I have a table called settingsTBL with only one row of data (used as storable settings). In this table their are columns for company name, address etc.

I'm using iTextSharp to generate an invoice from textboxes on a form. I've so far added all relevant textbox text into the PDF document, and would like to display the companys details at the bottom of the page but I'm having trouble getting it from the table, and into text on the PDF document.

I have created strings to try and use them to produce the text. Here is my code:

```
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
    string Query = "select * from settingsTBL where Reference = 1; ";
    SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
    SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    SqlCeDataReader myReader;
    try {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read()) {
            string sCompany = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Company Name"));
            string sAddress1 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Address Line 1"));
            string sAddress2 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Address Line 2"));
            string sPost = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Post Code"));
            string sTelephone = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Telephone Number"));
            string sEmail = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Email Address"));
            string sRegistration = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Registration Number"));
        }
        //displays a system error message if a problem is found
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
Paragraph lwa = new Paragraph("WOULD LIKE TO INSERT COMPANY DETAILS INTO HERE");
lwa.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
invoice.Add(lwa);
```

Comment: I've edited your question to format the code and while doing so, I've read your code. However, I think some data is missing: how are you filling out the form? Are you using `AcroFields`? What are the company details? As far as I can see, you already have those in `sCommpany`, `sAddress1`, `sAddress2`, etc. This contradicts with *"I'm having trouble getting it from the table"*. Also: if you can add other info, why is adding the company info different? What is happening when you try adding it?

Comment: Also, you are declaring your variables inside of a `while` loop. The moment the loop ends those variables go out of scope and are no longer available.

Comment: What you mean by "filling out the form"? The company details are detailed in the string definitions. All the other information is coming from textbox text that is inserted into the form, when the user clicks "Generate" it then inserts that into Paragraphs in iTextSharp PDF. The company information is in the settingsTBL (column names : Company Name, Telephone Number etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
            string Query = "select * from settingsTBL where Reference = 1; ";
            SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlCeDataReader myReader;

                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                myReader.Read();

                    string sCompany = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Company Name"));
                    string sAddress1 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Address Line 1"));
                    string sAddress2 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Address Line 2"));
                    string sPost = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Post Code"));
                    string sTelephone = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Telephone Number"));
                    string sEmail = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Email Address"));
                    string sRegistration = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Registration Number"));










        Paragraph lwa = new Paragraph(""+sCompany+ "\n " +sAddress1+ " " + sAddress2+"\n " +sPost+"\n Email Address: " + sEmail+ "\n Telephone: " +sTelephone+ "\n " +sRegistration+"" );

        lwa.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        invoice.Add(lwa);
```

Removing the { } and the while loop appears to work perfectly. Any further suggestions feel free to comment or answer. I'm always looking to find better answers.